# Three Sum to N in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there a better way than this example to find three numbers from a list that sum to zero in scala? Right now, I feel like my functional way may not be the most efficient and it contains duplicate tuples. What is the most efficient way to get rid of duplicate tuples in my current example?

```
def secondThreeSum(nums:List[Int], n:Int):List[(Int,Int,Int)] = {
  val sums = nums.combinations(2).map(combo => combo(0) + combo(1) -> (combo(0), combo(1))).toList.toMap

  nums.flatMap { num =>
    val tmp = n - num
    if(sums.contains(tmp) && sums(tmp)._1 != num && sums(tmp)._2 != num) Some((num, sums(tmp)._1, sums(tmp)._2)) else None
  }
}
```

Comment: I think one of the more efficient sreategies... is to  1) Sort the list. 2) Add largest and smallest numbers... search for third number ( such that sum == 0) using binary search. If you get sum 0, then save that tuple. Else... take these two binary search numbers ( where the sum crosses 0) as the second number. Check using binary search. Keep it up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple, and doesn't repeat any tuples:

```
def f(nums: List[Int], n: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
  for {
    (a, i) <- nums.zipWithIndex;
    (b, j) <- nums.zipWithIndex.drop(i + 1)
    c <- nums.drop(j + 1)
    if n == a + b + c
  } yield (a, b, c)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how much runtime efficiency am I losing here? Is this solution O(n^3)?

Comment: This will return duplicate tuples. Try running `f(List(1,2,3,3), 6)`.

Comment: @Marth, depends how you define "duplicate", I considered those two be distinct since they are made from distinct elements of the list.  The code will not produce tuples that reuse the same elements, even if the element values appear multiple times.  Otherwise, you know, `.distinct`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.combinations(3)` to generate all *distinct* possible triplets of your start list, then keep only those that sum up to `n` :

```
scala> def secondThreeSum(nums:List[Int], n:Int):List[(Int,Int,Int)] = {
         nums.combinations(3)
             .collect { case List(a,b,c) if (a+b+c) == n => (a,b,c) }
             .toList
       }
secondThreeSum: (nums: List[Int], n: Int)List[(Int, Int, Int)]

scala> secondThreeSum(List(1,2,3,-5,2), 0)
res3: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((2,3,-5))

scala> secondThreeSum(List(1,2,3,-5,2), -1)
res4: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,3,-5), (2,2,-5))
```

Comment: Thanks, how much runtime efficiency am I losing here? Is this solution O(n^3)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that's O(n^2*log(n)). So it's quite a lot faster for large lists.
Also it uses lower level language features to increase the speed even further.

```
def f(nums: List[Int], n: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
  val result = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[(Int, Int, Int)]
  val array = nums.toArray
  val mapValueToMaxIndex = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]
  nums.zipWithIndex.foreach {
    case (n, i) => mapValueToMaxIndex += (n -> math.max(i, (mapValueToMaxIndex.getOrElse(n, i))))
  }
  val size = array.size
  var i = 0
  while(i < size) {
    val a = array(i)
    var j = i+1
    while(j < size) {
      val b = array(j)
      val c = n - b - a
      mapValueToMaxIndex.get(c).foreach { maxIndex =>
        if(maxIndex > j) result += ((a, b, c))
      }
      j += 1
    }
    i += 1
  }
  result.toList
}
```